# Share XML documentation across overloads

Tags: c#, documentation, parameters

Is there a way to share XML documentation of the parameters to all the overloads? Let's say I have 10 overloads of a method but they all share the first 5 parameters (I use C# so I cannot have optional parameters).

How do I do it so that I do not have to write the same text for all of the parameters?

Comment: Copy/paste is just going to be easier/faster unless you have more than a dozen objects.

Comment: Yeah I know but it feels wrong in my object oriented brain to copy paste when programming :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  The task could be automated but the same text will have to be there for the compiler.

Comment: What do you mean by automated?

Comment: I mean that you could write a tool that could populate the XML documentation for your overrides.  You would have to run that before you run the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer your question, but I find that when I get more than 5-8 overloads, it is simpler to provide a simple POCO with every possible argument.

This gives me a place to embed validation and add as many properties as I like at a later date, and it's a single place to add xml docs.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer! Might use this in some other case but in this case it is not possible(lots of parameters that I create an object after calling the method which would lead to having to create the object before calling the method each time(which can be many places). 

I have used this in other projects however and there it works fine to the solution is solid